# Nodejs calling api updated data not refreshing

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to figure out why my api data not refreshing in node. I'm using local node and express calling api which works fine.

The issue I'm have getting the data from the api using setInterval doesn't output the new data.
I will need to stop/restart nodemon app.js each time, to get the updated api data.

Here's my setup.

```
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

async function getCandleTicks(interval) {
    try {

        const candles = await client.getTicks(
            'stocktick',  //
            'symbol',      //
        );
        app.get('/', (req, res) => {
            console.log('load data');
            res.send(candles);
        });
        
        // do something with the data
    } catch (error) {
        // handle the error
        console.log('error', error);
    }
}


//Calling api using set interval works but the data is the same when I refresh the browser. I need to stop and restart to see updated stock ticks 

getCandleTicks('1m'); // Calling to get data the first time
var t = setInterval(function () { 
    getCandleTicks('1m'); // Doesn't reload data. 
}, 6000);


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Hello world app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: Calling app.get is most likely what is giving you the same data. Try removing it and just putting `res.send(candles)`.  Also use node-cron for task scheduling.

Comment: Where will I display the data if I remove app.get '/' ?   Currently, I'm checking for the response data in an outside file like this $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/', 
to get the api json from node. I  like how node-cron looks. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is basically trying to reassign the function. Try to avoid it and instead have a variable that keeps changing and send the variable as such:

```
let candles = 0;

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send({
        candles
    });
});

function updateCandles() {
    candles += 1;
    // recursive function, keep updating every second
    setTimeout(updateCandles, 1000);
}
updateCandles();
```

Comment: Hey Danish, let me see how this works out. Thanks

Comment: How goes the progress @ifelse?